# JQuery animate script not working right away

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a jquery script to emulate the CSS3 transition property for IE. The script works but it doesn't work on the first hover. On the first hover it simply a regular hover that changes the picture and not the script and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0"}, 'slow');
},
function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
});
```

});

Here is the html

```
<ul id="gallery">

        <li class="engagement">
            <a
                href="engagements.html"
                style="background-image:url(Images/engagement2-small.jpg);"
            >
                <img
                    src="Images/engagement-small.jpg"
                    alt="Couple getting engaged"
                />
                Engagement Photos
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="weddings">
            <a
                href="weddings.html"
                style="background-image:url(Images/wedding2-small.jpg);"
            >
                <img
                    src="Images/wedding-small.jpg"
                    alt="Couple at wedding"
                />
                wedding photos
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="family">
            <a
                href="family.html"
                style="background-image:url(Images/family2-small.jpg);"
            >
                <img
                    src="Images/family-small.jpg"
                    alt="Young girl Posing for Family Photo"
                />
                family photos
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="seniors">
            <a
                href="senior.html"
                style="background-image:url(Images/senior2-small.jpg);"
            >
                <img
                    src="Images/senior-small.jpg"
                    alt="Young Woman Posing for Yearbook Photo"
                />
                senior portraits
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="corporate">
            <a
                href="corporate.html"
                style="background-image:url(Images/corporate2-small.jpg);"
            >
                <img
                    src="Images/corporate-small.jpg"
                    alt="Employees in Company Dresswear"
                />
                corporate photos
            </a>                 
        </li>

    </ul>
```

And here is the CSS although it doesn't work in IE

```
#gallery img {
    border:1px solid #E4E3E2;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#gallery a:focus img,
#gallery a:hover img {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code, or jsFiddle example, here. Don't link to your site if it can be avoided.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `regular hover that changes the picture and not the script`?

Comment: What is happening is that the first time you hover over the image instead of the smooth jquery effect fading the image out the image just disappears quickly. It is as if the script doesn't work until you hover over the image the first time. Not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: `animate()` might be confused about element dimensions if the images have not finished loading. A simple workaround (which may or may not be appropriate in your case), is to use `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. Trie using fadeTo and the same thing happens. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you're doing without showing more of your code (Whether you're navigating via Ajax etc.)

You could try using:

```
$('.page-class').live("pageshow", function() {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: The problem lies here:
`#gallery a:focus img,
#gallery a:hover img {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}`